# Right way to prevent additional events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Jquery I would like to suppress additional logic if my form didn't pass validation,this code work OK,

```
   $( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
        alert( "Form is invalid!" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I am wondering What is the differences between the three methods below
and which one to use?

```
Event.stopPropagation()
Event.cancelBubble()
Event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: `Event.cancelBubble` isn't a function, it's a property that you assign to. It's considered obsolete, and has been replaced with `Event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: return false;  should stop any thing else from executing --  if($("#uername").val() == ""){/*the user name was empty*/return false;}